# Java Read spcific items such as Title

Tags: java, html, url, bufferedreader

What I'm trying to accomplish read text (html) from a website that i have entered and stored in `str1`. I have been able to open the website and print all of the html code inside. but what I want to do is only print words between `<title><\title>` so i can print the title of the page.

```
URL oracle = new URL(str1);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

Comment: You need an HTML parser.

Comment: @SLaks - Since OP seemingly needs to parse just `<title>` which is used no more than once per page and always inside `<head>`, it can be done with rather simple crude logic.

Comment: the question title leaves this question open ended as being `generalized` by stating *specific items such as*, implies that `<title></title>` is an example, not the only thing, if that is the case the only correct answer is **use an html parser**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `StringBuilder` to read out all lines and append them to have the websites source in one string. Than you can easily search for `<title>` or `</title>` in this string.

Look at String functions like `indexOf` or `split`, to get exactly what's between those tags.

I'd recommend reading this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html